# Codename One Gui Builder I can't change the dialog position anymore

Tags: codenameone

I used the Gui Builder from Codename One and changed the position from the black dialog (with width and height) and now I can't reposition it again because the top of the Dialog is not reachable.
How can I reset the position from the dialog?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to delete the CN1Preferences file located in your %USERHOME%/.guiBuilder directory.  This will reset the window positions.